# Move 2sxc <script> to external file when it has razor content

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm trying to make my CSP without unsafe inline.
Since I have to manually check every file from every app, I may as well move the scripts to external files instead of creating a million word CSP entry in the web.config by adding hashes or nounces.

This seems easy enough for client side content, but many templates have razor code in then such as:

```
<script>
    alert(@myVar);
</script>
```

How can I move this to external?

Comment: I guess that was a bit succinct. What's a CSP?

Comment: Sorry. https://content-security-policy.com/unsafe-inline/

Answer (score 0):

So in general if you JS needs some input parameters you must of course put them somewhere, and only the razor will know what they are.

The simplest way is still to just have the initial call use the variables - like in your example above. If you have security concerns, doing type-checking in razor should eliminate that for you.

For example, if you do `@((int)thing.property)` than it simply cannot inject any unexpected payload.

If for some reason you really, really don't want this you can use a attribute-json convention, like

```
<div class="myGallery" init='{"files": 17}'> gallery contents </div>
```

and pick it up from the js you created. but this is quite a bit of work, so I would recommend the simpler way.